# Use Advance Join() with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to join this database structure

```
list : [
 {
  Qte : 5,
  Detail : 'A',
 },
 {
  Qte : 1,
  Detail : 'B',
 },
],
```

Into a string like that :

```
This.mydetail = '5 x A , 1 x B';
```

I tried to use that code in vuejs to join my table

```
{{ list.join(' , ') }}
```

But it's not working in my case, any orientation please ? thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
list.map(({Qte, Detail}) => `${Qte} x ${Detail}`).join(', ');
```

This [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over list and [destructures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) each list item into `Qte` and `Detail`, and finally uses a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create an array of strings like:

`[ '5 x A', '1 x B' ]`

A simple [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) then returns the final output:

`'5 x A, 1 x B'`

Comment: Works fine. Thank you !